# Add Zoom Button in ReportViewer Toolbar

Tags: reporting-services

I 'm working with Reporting Services in C # with processingMode = Remote, but reports do not show the zoom button and I need this button, the information is very small, it is hard to read. How can I show it with Mozilla or Chrome? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `Ctrl` + Mouse Wheel Up / Down...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use IE as a browser. Unfortunately, SSRS does not support all features in the browsers other than Internet Explorer.

Comment: The problem is that users use more chrome than internet explorer and I cann´t say  them which use.